# how can I mock a component when I make a storyBook?

Tags: vue.js

I'm making a storyBook out of a component that we'll call `ParentComponent`, it has a child called `ChildComponent`.

Inside `ChildComponent` there is a function that makes a call to the code of another repository so this is where the storybook fails.

```
components: {
  DataProvider:  () => import("common-data-provider"),// --> problem this line
}
```

How can I mock `ChildComponent` and not make this request?

StoryBook of Parent Component

```
  import articlesFunds from "../__fixtures__/articles.json";

    export default {
        component: ParentComponent,
        argTypes: {
            getConfigFilesDataProvider: {
                control: "object",
            },
        },
        args: {
            getConfigFilesDataProvider: () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: articlesFunds }))),
        },
    };

    export const Default = (args) => ({
        components: { ParentComopnent },
        props: Object.keys(args),
        template: `
            <ParentComopnent
            :data-provider="getConfigFilesDataProvider"
            />
        `,
    });
```

ChildComponent

```
   <template>
            <DataProvider :data="articles" />
            
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        name: "ChildComponent",
        components: {
            DataProvider:  () => import("common-data-provider"),// --> problem this line
            ComponentB
        },
        props: {
            articles: {
                type: Array,
                required: true,
            },
        }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: You can't do this in a normal way. Proceed from the fact that your comps should be flexible enough to allow that. Use slots, or flag props to modify default behaviuor

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm a bit new to this topic, could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storybook doesn't specifically provide the support for module mocking, but it's possible to use [Webpack aliases](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/build-pages-with-storybook#mocking-imports) for that.

Dependency injection of any kind can be used to modify the behaviour of a component in uncommon conditions, e.g. the ability to provide custom component:

```
    props: {
        articles: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        dataProvider: {
           type: null,
           default: () => import("common-data-provider"),
        }
    }
```

And used like dynamic component:

```
<component :is="dataProvider" :data="articles"/>
```

Then custom implementation can be provided through `dataProvider` prop.

Comment: thanks ut I dont understand you...  what happens with: `components: {
            DataProvider:  () => import("common-data-provider")` should I erase that line?

Comment: Yes. I added the missing part, it should be used as dynamic comp

Comment: ohh thanks! and what is `<component` ?

Comment: See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: I started a bounty, can you help me please ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73665933/how-can-i-make-an-enum-to-choose-between-one-data-or-another-in-a-storybook