# How can I make an enum to choose between one data or another in a storybook?

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I want the user to be able to select whether to use one of these jsons: `DataA` or `DataB`.

With this code only loads `DataA`.

```
   args: {
            getData: () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: dataA }))),
```

How can I fix it?

```
import dataA from "../__fixtures__/dataA.json";
import dataB from "../__fixtures__/dataB.json";

export default {
    component: ParentComponent,
    argTypes: {
        getData: {
            control: "function",
        },
    },
    args: {
        getData: () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: dataA }))),
    },
};

export const Default = (args) => ({
    components: { ParentComopnent },
    props: Object.keys(args),
    template: `
        <ParentComopnent
        :getData="getData"
        />
    `,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that story control needs to specifically select a dataset, similarly shown in the [documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#dealing-with-complex-values), something like:

```
argTypes: {
    dataset: {
      options: ['dataA', 'dataB'],
      mapping: { dataA, dataB },
      defaultValue: dataA,
    }
},
```

Then a value that depends on a dataset can be computed in story component:

```
computed: {
  getData() {
    return this.dataset ?
      new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: this.dataset }))) :
      null;
  }
},
template:  ...
```

Comment: thanks genius, what should I put in `args` object?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's needed, but try `args: { dataset: dataA }` instead of defaultValue in argTypes in case it's required

Comment: I can't see the dropdown on the `controls` section

Comment: Can you try to add ` control: { type: 'select' }` for argTypes dataset? It's supposed to be not needed but I cannot confirm that. In case there's still none, are there any errors?